# Encode facebook url image to BASE 64 string in android

Tags: android, facebook, base64, encode

Let me explain my problem.

I am trying to set Facebook profile image in app Imageview some thing like this ..

```
// Getting Facebook URL image and converting same to bitmap
Bitmap mIcon1;


URL img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ userProfileID +"/picture?type=square");
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream(), null, options);
```

Then after ..

```
// I am setting bitmap to imageview .. some thing like ..

if(mIcon1!=null) {
   user_picture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
}
```

Up to here it is working great ...

Now I need to save that Facebook Profile image into my DB located at server ...

I am performing that stuff some thing like ..

```
// Created a method for encoding ..
 public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image)
  {
      Bitmap immagex=image;
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
      immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
      byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
      String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

      Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
      return imageEncoded;
  }


// Now trying to use this method to get encoded BASE 64 image in string ..

String final_image = encodeTobase64(mIcon1);
```

Now when I try to send this string to my server then at server end I am recieving broken link ... Instead I must say that it's not working ..

**I need to perform two of stuff**

- Encode Facebook profile image to Encoded BASE 64 string so as to send same to server.
- Get type of image (i.e.  PNG/ JPG ... ) or compress and send that image in one specific format.

Looking forward for any suggestion on this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got solution of this and hope this will help some one ..

**@ Base concept :--** We generally use `GET` or `POST` method while sending data to server.
**1- GET:--** In this method you can only send specific amount of data ..
**2- POST :--** In this method you can send huge amount of data ..

**Problem was :--** Exact problem was that .. I was using `GET` method while sending data to server. Above mentioned concept was know to me . but, some how I did that mistake.

**Solution :--** You simply need to send data to server using `POST` method instead of `GET`.

Complete solution for this in undermentioned :--

```
// Define your ASYNC TASK like .. 


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                new ImageTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            } else{
                new ImageTask().execute();

            }
```

**AND**

```
// Now here comes your complete Async Task over here ..

 private class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
            Bitmap mIcon1;

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    URL img_value = null;
                    Log.d("taking", "2");
                    try {
                        if(type_of_login.equalsIgnoreCase("facebook")){

                            img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ user_id +"/picture?type=square");
                            System.out.println("Complete URl is:============================= " + img_value);

                        }else{

                            img_value = new URL("https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/"+ user_id +"?sz=50");
                            System.out.println("Complete URl is:============================= " + img_value);

                        }
                        //img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ userProfileID +"/picture?type=square");
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream(), null, options);
                        Log.d("taking", "3" + img_value);
                        Log.d("taking", "3" + mIcon1);
                        Log.d("taking", String.valueOf(mIcon1));

                        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        mIcon1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
                        byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                        encoded_image =Base64.encodeToString(ba,Base64.DEFAULT);

                        System.out.println("Encoded image is : ===== " + encoded_image);

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {



            if(mIcon1!=null)
          {
                user_pic.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
                get_string_image = encodeTobase64(mIcon1);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

           }
            }
        }
```

Now finally our dream method ..

```
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image)
      {
          Bitmap immagex=image;
          ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
          immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
          byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
          String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

          Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
          return imageEncoded;
      }
```

Now when you need to send data over API then simply execute `HttpPost` instead of `HttpGet`

That's it .. you are good to go with this ..